# Grouping together columns and populating accordingly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that can have a large amount of columns. The name of each column is 3 identical characters followed by a fourth unique character. I am trying to look at each "group" of columns to determine if they are '-'. If empty, I want to populate each element in each column simply with an 'X'

ex df:

```
aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ddd1 ggg1 ggg6 ggg8 fff9
 -     -   -    -     1    x   a     -    c   -    a     3    -    -    - 
 -     -   -    -     s    z   1     a    2   -    -     -    -    h    - 
 -     -   -    -     -    x   i     -    c   -    a     3    -    -    - 
 -     -   -    -     -    -   -     -    -   f    -     2    -    2    -
```

In this example there are two 'blank' groups -- aaa, fff

The resulting df would be like so:

```
aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ddd1 ggg1 ggg6 ggg8 fff9
 X     X   X    X     1    x   a     -    c   -    a     3    -    -    X 
 X     X   X    X     s    z   1     a    2   -    -     -    -    h    X 
 X     X   X    X     -    x   i     -    c   -    a     3    -    -    X 
 X     X   X    X     -    -   -     -    -   f    -     2    -    2    X
```

The part that has me lost is how to compare the columns as groups. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: What does `empty` mean in this case, because I see a `-`. Are these `NaN` in your original data?

Comment: @Erfan Updated question. `empty == '-' `. They are not `NaN`

Answer (score 3):

```
# Set comprehension to get each group.
col_groups = {col[:3] for col in df}  
# Dictionary comprehension to get the related columns for each group.
col_groups = {group: [c for c in df if c.startswith(group)] 
              for group in col_groups}
# >>> col_groups
# {'bbb': ['bbb1', 'bbb2', 'bbb3', 'bbb4'],
#  'ggg': ['ggg1', 'ggg6', 'ggg8'],
#  'aaa': ['aaa1', 'aaa2', 'aaa3', 'aaa4'],
#  'fff': ['fff9'],
#  'ccc': ['ccc1', 'ccc2'],
#  'ddd': ['ddd1']}

# Set the column values to `X` where all the values for each column in the group equals `-`.
for cols in col_groups.values():
    if df[cols].eq('-').all().all():
        df.loc[:, cols] = 'X'
>>> df
  aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ddd1 ggg1 ggg6 ggg8 fff9
0    X    X    X    X    1    x    a    -    c    -    a    3    -    -    X
1    X    X    X    X    s    z    1    a    2    -    -    -    -    h    X
2    X    X    X    X    -    x    i    -    c    -    a    3    -    -    X
3    X    X    X    X    -    -    -    -    -    f    -    2    -    2    X

col_groups
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
idx = (df == '-').groupby(df.columns.str[:3], axis=1).all().all().loc[lambda x: x].index
u_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str[:3].isin(idx)]
df.loc[:, u_cols] = 'X'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ddd1 ggg1 ggg6 ggg8 fff9
0    X    X    X    X    1    x    a    -    c    -    a    3    -    -    X
1    X    X    X    X    s    z    1    a    2    -    -    -    -    h    X
2    X    X    X    X    -    x    i    -    c    -    a    3    -    -    X
3    X    X    X    X    -    -    -    -    -    f    -    2    -    2    X
```

#### Details:

1. First create a boolean matrix; True where element equals '-'.
2. Group column wise on the first three characters of the column
   headers.
3. Check to see if all values in a column are True using `all`.
4. Use the indexes from these all True series to filter column headers
   to update dataframe.
5. Use `loc` with filtered datacolumn and assign 'X'.

Answer (score 1):

Try groupby `filter` and `.loc` assignment

```
m = df.groupby(df.columns.str[:3], axis=1).filter(lambda x: x.eq('-').all(None))
df.loc[:, m.columns] = 'X'

Out[305]:
  aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4 bbb1 bbb2 bbb3 bbb4 ccc1 ccc2 ddd1 ggg1 ggg6 ggg8 fff9
0    X    X    X    X    1    x    a    -    c    -    a    3    -    -    X
1    X    X    X    X    s    z    1    a    2    -    -    -    -    h    X
2    X    X    X    X    -    x    i    -    c    -    a    3    -    -    X
3    X    X    X    X    -    -    -    -    -    f    -    2    -    2    X
```

Comment: I like this answer also. :) +1

Comment: @ScottBoston: Thanks, +1 on yours too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of `'-'` in each column, `groupby` by the column name and calculate the mean of each group. If the mean is equal to the number of rows fill this group with `'X'`:

```
mask = df.eq('-').sum().groupby(df.columns.str[:3]).transform('mean').eq(len(df))
df.loc[:, mask] = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do is compare all of the lists in an if statement. Here is some pseudo-code to help you understand followed by some actual code:

```
# If aaa1 and aa2 and aaa3 and aaa4 is empty:
    # Fill all columns with X

isValueEmptyIncrament = 0
groupAAA = [aaa1, aaa2, aaa3, aaa4]
for subGroup in groupAAA:
    for i in subGroup:
        if i == "-":
            isValueEmptyIncrament += 1
    if isValueEmptyIncrament == len(subGroup):
        isSubGroupEmptyIncrament += 1
    isValueEmptyIncramentEmpty = 0
if isSubGroupEmptyIncrament == len(groupAAA):
    # I am guessing you can fill the rest, I ran out of time, here just fill the groups with X
```

Sorry if there is errors, I did this in 10 min and couldn't test it

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do this:

```
# First group the columns:

column_groups = {}
for col in df.columns:
    id = col[:3]
    if id not in column_groups:
        column_groups[id] = [col]
        continue
    column_groups[id].append(col)
```

Now we have a dictionary whose keys are the three letter ids and whose values are all of the columns belonging to the three letter id.

Next we iterate through the groups of columns:

```
for group in column_groups:
    if all(df[column_groups[group] == '-'):
        df[column_groups[group]] = ['X' for x in df[cols]]
```